# How to display HTML in RichTextField on blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I have simple HTML

```
<p>simple text</p>
<p>simple text</p>
```

I want to display it in RichTextField . How to do this???

Answer (score 1):

old discuss say you have to parse Html text. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Displaying-HTML-Data-in-TextField-RichTextField/td-p/1298771,

But you can also user BrowserField instate on RichTextField it will work proper.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a custom class to parse your HTML. There is a useful class called HTMLTextField from the [BB developer forums here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simple-HTMLTextField-implementation/m-p/454300/highlight/true#M90206)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i use this class it display text with html tags i need to remove html tags like <p> it display <p> tag on my screen text.